# Insert any element from script in an element Angular 2

Tags: html

I have a problem with insert an element in an element from `<my-app>`(angular 2).
i need at first to get the element `<div class="render"></div>` i do it with jQuery in `<script>` (look at code html) then need to write in `<div class="render"></div>` any information (for example `<h1> Hello </h1>` (look at HTML code) ). When the app run then code must will be to write in `<div class="render"></div>`. However that is not happen because on the moment start `<div class="render"></div>` is not exist. if to set setTimeOut then it's working (because `<div class="render"></div>` in time appear on page). Please Who may decide this problem?
P.S. JQuery and Angular 2 in one app this is not correctly I know about it but me need to decide the problem.

HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  </head>
<body>
<my-app>loading...</my-app>
<script> //there's try to get element '.render'
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#render").html('<h1> Hello </h1>');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular 2 app.component.html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <side-bar-left></side-bar-left>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12paddingMiddle"> 
                <div id="divSidebarRight">
                    <div class="render">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try and access the element from the .html file. Do it inside of your component using the AfterViewInit life cycle hook.

```
Import {AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'
```

add this to your class declaration

```
Class implements AfterViewInit
```

Then use your jquery in this function

```
    ngAfterViewInit (){
// jquery here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. You suggested me and I parsed a little in google and all works

Comment: That's great! Good luck!